# retry_non_idempotent in Logstash Http output

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

I am using the default settings [1] with the following config

```
        http {
            format=>"message"
            http_method=>"post"
            url=>"xxx"
            message=>'xxx'
        }
```

Which

```
retry_failed = true
automatic_retries = 1
retry_non_idempotent = false
```

I found that the failed POST request is being retried **infinitely**. Is my understanding correct?

[1] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-http.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two levels of retry in the http output. The automatic_retries and retry_non_idempotent options [control retries](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-mixin-http_client/blob/5d7c8de50ec159dc6a423aca5baa51004f17b800/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/http_client.rb#L109) inside the Manticore client that the http_client mixin wraps. The retry_failed option [controls retries](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-http/blob/2cca9dc4acea7dadd203a6b0645bac0d825888d1/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb#L177) in the http output itself.

If you set retry_failed to false then the Manticore client will still do automatic_retries, but the http output will not loop forever.